# How can I span my triple monitors so they act as one for gaming?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, games

I have an nvidia gtx960 and 3 identical monitors. They work great but they each act separately.

When gaming, I'd like to be able to span the game across all 3 monitors. I can't find where to enable this in the nvidia settings.

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10

EDIT:
I'm not sure why this is off topic. I'm wondering in Ubuntu how to enable whatever feature will use my 3 displays as one large display, similar to Eyefinity but with an nvidia card. I do not see any option for it in the nvidia-settings but I have seen it accomplished on youtube videos.

Comment: What game ? are you running with wine ?

Comment: I'm using steam I play multiple games

Comment: It is likely a steam bug , but various bug reports on the steam project / git indicate that it varies by game. http://bfy.tw/2eCF

Comment: I'm sure not all games support it, but I'm just wondering how to configure it in the first place. I haven't run across any bugs.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not a bug, (and thus) nor do I see why it would be off topic. Voting to reopen for clarity reasons, but I don't think it is possible.

Comment: If it doesn't get reopened I'll just ask again with clearer wording.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of Eyefinity is Surround for nVidia.

As for the answer:

If I speak referring to [here](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/surround/system-requirements), then sadly the answer is: you can't.

> Minimum System Requirements:
>
> Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7: 32-bit and 64-bit

**However**, I also found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors) that pretty much answers your question but... it is for Hardy Heron and might not (and probably will not) work on 15.10.

I also found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/476012/linux-nvidia-surround-3-monitors) which states what you try to get is achievable, but he doesn't explain "how?". Also this question is 3 years old.

And finally [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1999966). But this is on 12.04

I have found other sources that shows people use it on ubuntu but they are usually pretty old. Looking at all of them, my conclusion is nVidia might've stopped supporting Ubuntu with this feature. I suggest try to contact nVidia and get help from them.